# Predicting continuous event based on on time reports about this event

Tags: time-series

There is continuous event, for example someone is inside the room. He can walk in once a day for 10 hours, or 10 times a day for 30 min. About this event, we get one time reports. There is always report when the person enters the room, leaves and but also multiple reports when he is in the room. These reports are indistinguishable. We can also ask the person "are you in the room" and get sure answer, but we don’t want to do it too often to not get him irritated.

Now, the question is:
Now we want to know, based on these reports, is the person in the room? How to model something like this, to minimize number of manual questions asked?

Comment: That is the wrong question. You should ask if **the cat is still alive, or not**! Joke aside, this is not enough information to predict anything. **When is the person *not* in the room?

Answer (score 0):

You should develop your algorithm based on the reports; then only query the person when the algorithm returns its least confident results.  Because you would expect that the most valuable patterns would be near the decision boundaries.